# Add registry key during vsix installation

Tags: vsix, visual-studio-sdk, vsixmanifest

Is there any way to dynamically add a registry key while installing from a vsix?

For example:

Say we have SomeExtension.vsix.
It should check for a AnExisting.dll under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Existing\AnExisting.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Existing2\AnExisting.dll
```

Say it finds under Existing folder
Then add

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software]
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Existing"=""
```

I know of pkgdef, but it seems to be taking a constant value i.e. we cannot get it to dynamically change on the machine it is being installed.

Or is it possible to get an environment variable on the machine it is being installed say we set PRODUCT_HOME accordingly for the vsix to add the value to registry?

Comment: You can do it when your package loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the easiest way we can do this, although I do not know what side effects it can have. The following is a batch file snippet:

```
rem generate a pkgdef with the appropriate value
echo [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software] > MyBindingPaths.pkgdef
echo "%PRODUCT_HOME%"="" >> MyBindingPaths.pkgdef

rem *** Copy to VS extensions folder, this is a known location to look for pkgdef files ***
copy MyBindingPaths.pkgdef "%DEVENVDIR%Extensions"

echo *** Installing our VSIX ***
"%DevEnvDir%\vsixinstaller" -q SomeExtension.vsix
```

Other better suggestions welcome.